# Writing angular2 test for a service with constructor parameters

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

How can I test a service which uses constructor parameters? I'm trying to learn about testing via the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#isolated-service-tests), but am having trouble. I have a service `location-search.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable }       from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Jsonp }   from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }       from 'rxjs';

import { Location }         from '../models/location';

@Injectable()
export class LocationSearchService {
    constructor(private jsonp: Jsonp) {}

    search(term: string): Observable<Location[]> {
        return this.jsonp
            .get(/* api url */)
            .map((r: Response) => r.json().RESULTS as Location[]);
    }
}
```

Now, when I'm writing `location-search.spec.ts`, how can I properly inject `jsonp` into the service? e.g.

```
describe('LocationSearchService', () => {
  let service: LocationSearchService;

  // how do I initialize LocationSearchService with Jsonp in this case?
  beforeEach(() => { service = new LocationSearchService(); });

  it('#search should return observable value', () => {
    expect(service.search('term').toBe('observable value');
    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: When testing services that depends on angular services, I usually pass them a manually created instance of the object (Ex: service = new MyService(new NgService)). However, in this case, I would use a mock since you don't want your tests to depend on the backend. I'm not sure if angular already provide mocks for jsonp, you might have to code one.

Comment: I recommend taking a look at this resource:
https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/testing-services-in-angular-2